# How to display random banners if the number I need exceeds the amount of vocabulary terms?

Tags: views

I made a classified ads site in Drupal 6, now I am updating it to Drupal 9. I already have the "ads" part working, defining categories with a taxonomy vocabulary but displaying the ads with a Views page (custom URL).

I have an issue with banners. I succeeded in displaying a block with banners tagged with the same term.

BUT in my old site, using a module called "Advertisement", if I want to display 5 banners but have only three for the term, the module displayed two more, randomnly chosen.
Is there a way to achieve this with Views?

Thanks. Please forgive my bad English.

Comment: The Advertisement module exists for Drupal 9.

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering if there was a way to do it with Views only

Comment: Well, I've tried the module for Drupal 9 and it doesn't have any of the functionalities I need. Just a content type with a tracker